# surface plot does not show all x-axis value

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am trying to plot a surface in my dash app.

My x-axis has the 17 values below.

50, 60, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130, 140, 150

My y-axis has the 5 values below.

1, 3, 6, 12, 24.

Each x-y value is populate, there are no nan's.

The issue I have is that my plot does not show all my x-axis values. It starts at 50 & ends at 80, I have no idea why. Also the plot is quiet small, the figure is bigger. How can I see all my x-axis values?

Comment: can you include the code you used to create your plot? this isn't enough information to reproduce your surface plot or see what the problem is